# Starting a Firefoxprofile in a startupscript?

Tags: firefox, scripting, vbscript, startup

How do you start a Firefox-profile in a startupscript? This want do:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

progList = Array("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "PrimaryNew" -no-remote")



For Each prog in progList
    'WScript.Echo "File Name: " & prog
    shell.run """" & prog & """", 1, false
    WScript.sleep 10000 '10 seconds
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Exec` instead of `Run`

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ff = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote -p " 'Firefox path and cmd args
profileList = Array("profile1","profile2","profile3") 'array of profile names
For Each prof in profileList
    'WScript.Echo "File Name: " & ff & prof
    shell.Exec(ff & prof)
    WScript.sleep 10000 '10 seconds
Next
```